# Como definir a semântica de pacotes baixados com composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Criei alguns pacotes PHP com ajuda do composer como gerenciador de dependências e disponibilizei no Packagist (https://packagist.org/users/fabiojaniolima/packages/).

Após subir os pacotes fiz a instalação destes dentro de um projeto Laravel. Para isso utilizei a seguinte instrução:

```
composer require crphp/check
```

Ao olhar no composer.json do Laravel vi a seguinte linha:

```
"crphp/check": "^1.0"
```

Consigo definir dentro do pacote `crphp/check` para quando ele for instalado ele assumir outra semântica de versão, como por exemplo `1.1.*`?

E essa semântica "default" `^1.0` quer dizer o que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md):

> ## Caret
>
> The ^ operator behaves very similarly but it sticks closer to semantic
>   versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example
>   ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0 as none of the releases until
>   2.0 should break backwards compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats ^0.3 as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0.

Minha tradução:

> O operador `^` se comporta de forma muito semelhante, mas mais apegado às versões semântica, e sempre vai permitir atualizações sem quebras. Por exemplo, `^1.2.3` é equivalente a `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0`, que nenhum dos lançamentos até `2.0` deve quebrar compatibilidade com versões anteriores.
>   Para versões com valores menores que `1.0` também atua com segurança em mente e trata `^0.3` como `>=0.3.0 <0.4.0`.
>
> Este é o operador recomendado para o máximo de interoperabilidade ao escrever o código da biblioteca.

Ou seja, quando uso `^1.2.3`, estou dizendo ao composer *"instale a partir da versão 1.2.3 e, se tiver atualizações disponíveis, só atualize se for menor que a versão 2.0.0"*.

Creio que o Composer fez isso por conta de primeiro número da sequencia do versionamento indicar que a biblioteca teve mudança significativas e será dependente da versão do PHP que você usa. Isso que quer dizer "atualizações sem quebra" citada anteriormente.

Se você quer definir que sua instalação assumirá a versão semântica como `1.1`, então você deve especificar na instalação do seu Composer

```
composer require crphp/check 1.1.*
```

Ou

```
composer require crphp/check ^1.1
```